# Make element pretend like its not there but still be visible WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a listbox with this in it:

```
<ListBoxItem>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <CheckBox Margin="0 0 5 0"></CheckBox>
        <TextBlock>hi stackoverflow</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</ListBoxItem>
```

For some reason if you try to click on the ListBoxItem in the place where the StackPanel shows up, it clicks on the StackPanel and not on the ListBoxItem.

[ListBoxItem on hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzwrA.png)

Is there a way to make the StackPanel only be visible and not interactable so that it doesn't get in the way when the user tries clicking on a ListBoxItem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your requirement I have make use of **IsHitTestVisible** property for TextBlock and I have also make a stackpanels **Background** property to **Null** so that it will not sense any mouse event on stackpanel.

```
     <ListBox>
        <ListBoxItem>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="{x:Null}">
                <CheckBox Margin="0 0 5 0"></CheckBox>
                <TextBlock IsHitTestVisible="true">hi stackoverflow</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
```

Hope the solution is compatible with your all requirements.